# Display at most 3 transaction for each user

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have this table.

```
users|amount
------------
User1|  500
User1|  400
User1|  300
User1|  200
User1|  100
User2|  500
User2|  400
User2|  300
User2|  200
User3|  300
User3|  200
```

I want to display at most 3 transaction for each user. The result given in the example should be this.

```
users|amount
------------
User1|  500
User1|  400
User1|  300
User2|  500
User2|  400
User2|  300
User3|  300
User3|  200
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL (MySQL)? What steps should I do?

Comment: should be **at most**

Comment: this is mysql right?

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
SELECT
    users, amount
FROM (SELECT
    users, amount,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY users ORDER BY amount DESC) AS rn
FROM yourtable) AS a
WHERE a.rn <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables for this:

```
SELECT users, amount
FROM (
  SELECT users, amount,
         @grp := IF(@usr = users, @grp + 1,
                    IF(@usr := users, 1, 1)) AS grp
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 0, @usr = '') AS vars
  ORDER BY users, amount DESC) AS t
WHERE t.grp <= 3
```

`@grp` variables enumerates records within each `users` partition. The outer query uses this variable in order to retrieve *at most* 3 records per user.

Comment: what does `:=` do?

Comment: @MrA It is used to assign a value to a variable

Comment: I tried this in MySQL5.5 and it doesn't work.